# How would one capture and upload a video from WP8 to OneDrive?

Tags: windows-phone-8, video-capture, live-sdk

So I have been working with the Live SDK for a few weeks. I've gotten an Android version of what I want done and I'm working on a Windows Phone 8 version. Basically, the goal is to create an app that can record a video and then upload that video to OneDrive. I am able to upload pictures to OneDrive currently on the app. However I have hit many walls when it comes to video. Firstly, apparently WP8 doesn't allow access to video files recorded. Secondly, I cannot find how to use the native camera for video recording and storing it where I can access it.

So really my question is how can I accomplish this on WP8? or is it even possible? Ideally I'd like to use the native camera and not write my own but if I have to I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly from my experience while working with Live SDK it does not matter what kind of files you are uploading.

As for video recording. You will have to create your own recorder and store those videos in your app's folder.

Comment: This is true that file types don't matter. Also, I was able to use my own recorder to save the files then upload them so I could have access to them. Thanks!